# Comparing MySQL and SQLite create table statements

Tags: mysql, sqlite

So I am trying to make an app with "code first" approach and active record ORM. I am willing to work with MySQL and SQLite (both) in this app. Here is how I am creating a database:

(this is a mockup table I came up with solely for this question)

```
    $this->int("id", self::INT_MEDIUM)->unSigned()->primaryKey()->autoIncrement();
    $this->string("hash", 64, self::STR_FIXED)->unique();
    $this->enum("status", "available","sold","pending")->defaultValue("available");
    $this->int("category", self::INT_MEDIUM)->unSigned()->defaultValue(0);
    $this->string("name")->unique();
    $this->text("descr")->nullable();
    $this->decimal("price", 10, 4)->defaultValue(1.234);
    $this->uniqueKey("store_np", "name", "price");
    $this->foreignKey("category", "categories", "id");
```

and then my code generates CREATE TABLE statement for me, here are the results:

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` mediumint UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY auto_increment NOT NULL,
  `hash` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('available','sold','pending') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default 'available',
  `category` mediumint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default 0,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descr` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL default 1.234,
  UNIQUE KEY (`hash`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `store_np` (`name`,`price`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `categories`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `hash` TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `status` TEXT CHECK(status in ('available','sold','pending') ) NOT NULL default 'available',
  `category` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL default 0,
  `name` TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `descr` TEXT default NULL,
  `price` REAL NOT NULL default 1.234,
  CONSTRAINT `store_np` UNIQUE (`name`,`price`),
  CONSTRAINT `cnstrnt_category_frgn` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `categories`(`id`)
);
```

I executed both queries in phpMyAdmin and phpLiteAdmin, and both seemed to worked fine.

Here are my concerns:

- For example, I didn't know I cannot use "UNSIGNED" with "PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" in SQLite, which gave me hard time to figure out. Is there anything else like that I should be concerned about?
- Even though both statements were executed successfully, are they going to work as expected? Especially the constraints in SQLite
- Please check "status" column in SQLite, is it appropriate method to use as an alternative to MySQL's enum?